# I want to hide rows above and below a value specified in $H$1 in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, hide, rows

I have a live mkts excel, in which I am searching for the CMP price defined in $H$1, and based on this value, search in entire column J, and then hide entire rows above and below this value, except the 10 rows preeceding above and below
code tried as below:

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim N As Long, i As Long
N = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

```
For i = 2 To N
    If InStr(1, Cells(i, "J"), "H1") > 0 Then J.Offset(-10, 0).EntireRow.Hidden = True
   ' MsgBox (DONE)
    'End If
Next i
```

End Sub

Comment: Use MATCH to find the row number and then hide the target rows

Comment: Can give an example please? Used this =MATCH(H1,J2:J26,1) and got number 15, so how do I hide rows above except 1st 10 rows from the match it using VBA

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72391349/use-cell-value-for-coordinates-to-hide-rows#comment127885675_72391349

Comment: Hey Foxfire....I did take a look at it, and edited the code as follows, I am getting the row selected using the code below, but not able to hide it                                                       ' Go to the applicable row.
    currRow = Worksheets("T2").Range("K" & FirstMatchRowNumber + 3).Select
    Rows(currRow & ":15").EntireRow.Hidden = True

Comment: Hey Foxfire,  I went to your suggested article and I saw this..... Rows(Range("B1").value & ":50").EntireRow.Hidden = True..... can you please let me know what does " :50 " do, and how do I go downwards from this selection?

Comment: When selectin rows, you do (1:50) to select rows 1 to 50, or (10:25) would be rows 10 to 25 and so on. If you want to do downwards, you need to calculate your target row. There are thousands of questions here that show how to get last non blank rows.